# Is it possible to create methods which will be accessible without import in scala?

Tags: scala

Forgive me for my childish question. I can not remember whether in past I read somewhere of making `predef` like method/val in scala which can be accessible in the project without any import keyword. Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

- using full names:

  ```
  // Full name require no imports.
  scala.util.Try(str.toLong)
  ```
- nested packages with `package` declaration broken down

  ```
  // Imports everything from com.package and com.package.subdomain
  // before establishing the package for all definitions in this file to
  // com.example.subdomain.controller
  // If you put shared definitions in common super-package they will be imported.
  // This convention is used e.g. everywhere in Scala NSC (scalac compiler).
  package com.example
  package subdomain
  package controller

  // your code here
  ```
- since 2.13 - `Yimports` option passed to compiler from your build tool

  ```
  // It always adds ._ after package/object name so you have to import everything.
  // It doesn't append new imports so if you want to keep the current ones
  // you have to repeat all the normally imported packages and objects.
  // You can use it to create your own Predef and add it to/replace
  // the default Scala Predef (though you have to remember that certain
  // features of it cannot be easily copied e.g. scala.Predef.classOf). 
  scalacOptions += "-Yimports:java.lang,scala,scala.Predef,cats.implicits"
  ```